# Trying to create bar charts form a Pandas Data Frame. Charts to be specific to the month

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

Dataframe contains essentially three things.

*Date, Count, and Company*.

I want to create a program that makes bar charts with count on the y axis and company on the x axis; but there should be multiple charts for different months. for.eg there should be a may chart containing all the  companies counts from that month only

Ive tried using groupby to organise them by company and using .sum() to count up for the whole database per company but am not able to do it also specific to a month

```
#code for grouping data by company only not dates
df = pd.read_csv('values.csv', delimiter = ',')

df.head(1)

df = df.query('Metric == "Company"')

df = df.groupby('Company').sum().Count

print(df)

df = df.plot(kind='bar', align='center', title ="entity",figsize=(15,10),legend=True, fontsize=5)
df.set_ylabel("Count",fontsize=12)
df.set_xlabel("Company",fontsize=12)
#this code works, variables changed for data privacy
```

The expected result should print out multiple graphs for each month containing all counts per company for that month only.

Comment: The Dataframe essentially contains three headings date, count, company

Comment: Could you please attach sample Data ?

Comment: Company Count Date
Apple 97 16/01/2019
Samsung 84 06/01/2019
Linux 100 03/02/2019
Microsoft 61 29/01/2019
Blackberry 17 24/02/2019
LG 98 23/02/2019
Panasonic 20 22/02/2019
Apple 100 19/03/2019
Samsung 43 02/01/2019
Linux 21 06/01/2019
Microsoft 72 05/03/2019
Blackberry 75 24/03/2019
LG 82 19/03/2019
Panasonic 42 25/02/2019
Apple 50 12/01/2019
Samsung 74 15/02/2019
Linux 41 09/03/2019
Microsoft 97 12/03/2019
Blackberry 15 28/03/2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can get months , years , day separated from the date column. ([use to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html))

> Now you have **Date, Count, company, Month, year, Date columns**

```
df = df.groupby(['month','Company']).sum() #month-company combo and counts
fig = plt.figure()
for i,m in enumerate(df['month'].unique()): 
    plt.subplot(2,3,i+1)
    tmp = df[df['Month']==m]
    plt.bar(tmp['company'],tmp['count'])
    plt.title(m)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thxs for your response, but it returns me with a Type error: on line df = df.grouby... series object is not callable

Comment: Check now . 
PS: You need to create Month columns

Comment: Hi, Thxs for your response, I think I can make it work from here on, however I am getting a key error on the: for, i,m in enumerate(df["month"].uniqure())

Comment: check your unique() spelling. If you think the answer was relevant to what was asked please accept it as official answer :)